# How to use both TMemo and TRichEdit using the same variable name

Tags: delphi, vcl

I use the variable name `Memo1` in my VCL application. It is a `TMemo`, as usual.

However, I want users to choose between `TMemo` and `TRichEdit`. My legacy code uses `Memo1` thousands of times. So, I want to keep the variable name `Memo1` whatever the user chooses. Fortunately, `TMemo` and `TRichEdit` have almost the same properties and methods.

I want to create `Memo1` like this:

```
if UserChoice='TMemo' then
begin
  Memo1:=TMemo.Create(self);
end else
begin
  Memo1:=TRichEdit.Create(self);
end;
Memo1.Parent:=self;
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Declare `Memo1` as `TWinControl`, not `TMemo`. But you'll probably find that quite a few properties are not introduced at this common ancestor. But perhaps you can work with window messages. I think the edit control and the Rich Edit control have quite a few messages in common.

Comment: Also, why do you need this: What can you do in a `TMemo` that you cannot do in a `TRichEdit`?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand It worked!!! TWinControl and (Memo1 as TRichEdit) did the trick! Thank you very much. Some users prefer TMemo.

Comment: @XelNaga `(Memo1 as TRichEdit)` won't work when `Memo1` is pointing at a `TMemo`. A better common ancestor to use between `TMemo` and `TRichEdit` is `TCustomMemo` rather than `TWinControl`

Comment: @RemyLebeau is right. I was lazy and didn't even bother to have a look at the precise hierarchy.